# Getting field value from another table returns a json collection in Laravel

Tags: laravel, database, eloquent, laravel-8, eloquent-relationship

I am using Laravel orchid package and in layout file, I have this function:

```
 protected function columns(): iterable
    {
        $org = '';
        $employeeDetails = '';
        return [
            TD::make('Userid', __('User Id'))
            ->cantHide()
            ->sort()
            ->filter(Input::make()),
            TD::make($employeeDetails, __('Employee Name'))
            ->filter(Input::make())
            ->render(function(DailyAttendance $attendance) {
                $employeeDetails = Employee::where('employeeCode', $attendance->Userid)->first(['employeeName']);
                
                return $employeeDetails;
                
            })
            ->sort(),
           
        ];
    }
```

The result is not picking employee name but whole with field name like this:

[image]

There are 2 tables one which is getting attendance logs based on userid and another table which is storing employee records like name and organizaion based on userid.

How can I only get the employee name using first or get.

I tried get('fieldname') but it is also returning the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try remove the initialization of `$employeeDetails` and pass `employeeName` as the first argument to `TD::make()` in the second column definition.
Then in the render() method, you can use `pluck('employeeName')` instead of `first(['employeeName'])` to get only the employee name:

```
 TD::make('employeeName', __('Employee Name'))
```

and

```
$employeeDetails = Employee::where('employeeCode', $attendance->Userid)->pluck('employeeName')->first();
```